# Show only records with count greater than certain number using aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to only show the records which have a sum greater than or equal to four. This isn't working.

```
const bookings = await Booking.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$bookingDate" } },
      totalBookings: {
        $sum: 1,
      },
    },
    $match: {
      sum: { $gte: 4 },
    },
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $dateToString: {
          format: "%Y-%m-%d",
          date: "$bookingDate",
          
        },
        
      },
      totalBookings: {
        $sum: 1,
        
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      totalBookings: {
        $gte: 4,
        
      },
      
    },
    
  },
  
])
```

There is a mismatch. Your key is `totalBookings` but not `sum`

EDIT:

[Refer this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/g51iuzVqHbF)

Comment: Thanks for that. I am getting an error with this though; `Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators`

Comment: Can you add a mongoplayground with sample document? I think $group is not closed properly.

Comment: Sadly, I don't actually know how to use this mongo playground. But I gave it a try. https://mongoplayground.net/p/L5vNpBDnNBh

Comment: Refer my edit, it was syntax errors. Braces were mismatched, Date type was added to document

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. Not sure if it would be a quick comment or if I need to open a new question. I see the dates that are returned are all a day behind. So if the date was saved to the database as the 4th of June, it is showing as the 3rd of June?

Comment: Date is stored in UTC format in mongo. Check timezone differences.